# Issue with finding element on Amazon Seller homepage with VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, amazon-web-services

I recently came across a new problem while working with my Excel VBA code in order to automate the input a value from a cell (order number) into Amazon's search box and searching for the order. I can't seem to locate the proper object to reference the search button on the homepage of the Amazon Seller home page in order to click and proceed. My code is this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplorer
Sub MyAmazonSeller()
Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim MyURL As String
Dim oSignInLink As HTMLLinkElement
Dim oInputEmail As HTMLInputElement
Dim oInputPassword As HTMLInputElement
Dim oInputSigninButton As HTMLInputButtonElement
Dim oInputSearchOrder As HTMLInputElement
Dim oInputSearchButton As HTMLInputButtonElement


MyURL = "https://sellercentral.amazon.com/gp/homepage.html"

Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer

' Open the browser and navigate.
With MyBrowser
    .Silent = True
    .Navigate MyURL
    .Visible = True
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
End With


' Get the html document.
Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.Document

' See if you have the sign in link is because you are in the main
' page
Set oSignInLink = HTMLDoc.getElementById("signin-button-container")
If Not oSignInLink Is Nothing Then
    oSignInLink.Click
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until MyBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
End If

' Get the email field and the next button
Set oInputEmail = HTMLDoc.getElementById("username")
Set oInputPassword = HTMLDoc.getElementById("password")

' Click the button and wait
oInputEmail.Value = "xxxxxxxxx@xxxxxx.net"


' Get the password field and the sign in button
Set oInputPassword = HTMLDoc.getElementById("password")
Set oInputSigninButton = HTMLDoc.getElementById("sign-in-button")


' Click the button and wait
oInputPassword.Value = "xxxxxxxx"
oInputSigninButton.Click
  Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until MyBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE



Set oInputSearchOrder = HTMLDoc.getElementById("sc-search-field")
oInputSearchOrder.Value = "110-7706193-5695453"
Set oInputSearchButton = HTMLDoc.getElementByClassName("sc-search-button")
oInputSearchButton.Click
  Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until MyBrowser.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Err_Clear:
If Err <> 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    Resume Next
End If

End Sub
```

The section right before the Err_Clear is the new snippet of code I've been trying to modify and work with. It seems that the search button does not have a proper ID, so therefore is more difficult to reference. I am getting an Error 91 every time the code gets to the second to last snippet.

Comment: as a dirty workaraund -> `WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"`? more like a question :D